# Check input fields for numbers and hyphen

Tags: jquery

I just want to check if a input-value is numeric and/or has a hyphen between two numbers. Comma should be replaced by point (1,23 -> 1.23) and spaces should be deleted.

Allowed values are i.e.:

```
1
2
1-2
34-45
```

Not allowed:

```
-2
1-
-
any letters
```

My attempt:

```
$('form').submit(function( event ) {
    $('input').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).val($(element).val().replace(",", ".").replace(" ", "")); // replace comma, delete spaces
    if (!$.isNumeric($(element).val())) {
        alert("error");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    // else submit
});
```

I think `isNumeric` is the wrong way, as '12-5' should be a valid value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to do is to replace the `,` with `.` and remove spaces. This can be done by:

`var input = "1 2 3. 4 - 56,78"; input.replace(/ /g,"").replace(/,/g,".")`

Then you have to apply regex:

`/^\d+(\.\d+|\d*)(-?\d+(\.\d+|\d*)|\d*)$/`

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y5ACh/1/

regex explanation: http://www.regexr.com/397j6

forgot to mention - I assumed that strings like `.2-31` are invalid (`$.isNumeric(".2")` returns true, so we can't use `$.isNumeric` on each, before and after `-`)

---

For floats to be invalid you need to drop the  `(\.\d+|\d*)` groups: http://jsfiddle.net/y5ACh/2/

For integers to be invalid you need to drop the `\d*` groups: http://jsfiddle.net/y5ACh/3/

Comment: How do I have to change the code if I want to allow only numbers without digits? I mean '3.5-6' would be invalid...

Comment: @user3142695 updated the answer - is this what you meant? Or can you explain - should it be invalid due to `3.5` or due to `6`?

Comment: '3.5-6' should be invalid due to 3.5. So the second link works properly for that case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).val($(element).val().replace(",", ".").replace(" ", "")); // replace comma, delete spacesis).val());
    //alert($(this).val());
    if (!$.isNumeric($(element).val())) {
        alert("error");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/y9Tpa/

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not what I need. i.e. this should be correct: http://jsfiddle.net/y9Tpa/1/. Please have a look at the examples of my post. '1-2' should be a correct value...